# Sum array/list values based on critera

Tags: ruby

Given an array of the array [X,Y]:

```
a=[[1,2],[2,2],[3,2],[4,2],[5,2],[6,2]]
```

What is the most efficient way to sum all the Y digits for `2<=X<4`?

Comment: It seems unimportant, but collections should have plural names (`xs`, `pairs`, whatever). IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

I'd work with this:

```
a.select{ |x,y| (2...4) === x }.inject(0){ |m, (x,y)| m + y }
=> 4
```

I don't really like using `...` though, because it confuses people by how it works. Here are some equivalent ways of testing:

```
a.select{ |x,y| (2..3) === x }.inject(0){ |m, (x,y)| m + y }
ary.select{ |x,y| (2 <= x) && (x < 4) }.inject(0){ |m, (x,y)| m + y } } }
```

Here's some benchmark code:

```
require 'benchmark'

a = [ [1,2], [2,2], [3,2], [4,2], [5,2], [6,2] ]
n = 1_000_000

Benchmark.bm(12) do |b|
  b.report('The Tin Man')  { n.times { a.select{ |x,y| (2...4) === x }.inject(0){ |m, (x,y)| m + y } } }
  b.report('The Tin Man2') { n.times { a.select{ |x,y| (2 <= x) && (x < 4) }.inject(0){ |m, (x,y)| m + y } } }
  b.report('Mik_Die')      { n.times { a.select{ |i| (2...4).include? i[0] }.map(&:last).reduce(:+) } }
  b.report('Justin Ko')    { n.times { a.inject(0){ |sum, coord| (coord[0] >= 2  and coord[0] < 4) ? sum + coord[1] : sum } } }
  b.report('Justin Ko2')   { n.times { a.inject(0){ |sum, (x,y)| (x >= 2  and x < 4) ? sum + y : sum } } }
  b.report('Leo Correa')   { n.times { sum = 0; a.each { |x, y| sum += y if x >= 2 and x < 4 } } }
  b.report('tokland')      { n.times { a.map { |x, y| y if x >= 2 && x < 4 }.compact.inject(0, :+) } }
end
```

And its output:

```
                   user     system      total        real
The Tin Man    4.020000   0.000000   4.020000 (  4.020154)
The Tin Man2   2.420000   0.000000   2.420000 (  2.424424)
Mik_Die        3.830000   0.000000   3.830000 (  3.836531)
Justin Ko      2.070000   0.000000   2.070000 (  2.072446)
Justin Ko2     2.000000   0.000000   2.000000 (  2.035079)
Leo Correa     1.260000   0.000000   1.260000 (  1.259672)
tokland        2.650000   0.010000   2.660000 (  2.645466)
```

The lesson learned here is `inject` is costly.

Comment: `+=` can be replaced by simple `+`

Comment: That's true. I was thinking in terms of summing into `m`, but inject will do that correctly.

Comment: Is doing a select before the sum more efficient then just an inject below?

Comment: It's not done for efficiency, it's done for clarity. I'll do a benchmark to figure out whether it's more efficient.

Comment: I've never used benchmark, but will start, just for clarify, I thought I lower number is better.  as in the process takes less time. Based on @Tinman's comments, "inject" is costly, would mean, it takes more time and is less efficient, however, it has the least time, what am I misunderstanding?  thanks!

Comment: @leocorrea doesn't use `inject` in his answer, and it's the fastest of them all. All the others that use `inject` took longer, therefore, they're more costly.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking mostly a JustinKO, you are right. a simple each loop seems the best. Wow!

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
a = [[1,2],[2,2],[3,2],[4,2],[5,2],[6,2]]
sum = a.inject(0){ |sum, (x,y)| (x >= 2  and x < 4) ? sum + y : sum }
puts sum
#=> 4
```

The rdoc describes the `inject` method well:

> inject(initial) {| memo, obj | block } → obj
>
> Combines all elements of enum by applying a binary operation,
>   specified by a block or a symbol that names a method or operator.
>
> If you specify a block, then for each element in enum the block is
>   passed an accumulator value (memo) and the element. If you specify a
>   symbol instead, then each element in the collection will be passed to
>   the named method of memo. In either case, the result becomes the new
>   value for memo. At the end of the iteration, the final value of memo
>   is the return value for the method.
>
> If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo, then uses
>   the first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo.

**Update - Benchmark Array vs Unpacking:**

@tokland had suggested unpacking the pairs, which definitely improves readability. The following benchmark was run to see if it was faster than using the array (ie my original solution).

```
require 'benchmark'

a = [ [1,2], [2,2], [3,2], [4,2], [5,2], [6,2] ]
n = 2_000_000

Benchmark.bm(12) do |b|
  b.report('array'){n.times{a.inject(0){ |sum, coord| (coord[0] >= 2  and coord[0] < 4) ? sum + coord[1] : sum }}}
  b.report('unpacked'){n.times{a.inject(0){ |sum, (x,y)| (x >= 2  and x < 4) ? sum + y : sum }}}
end
```

Which gave the results

```
                   user     system      total        real
array          3.916000   0.000000   3.916000 (  3.925393)
unpacked       3.619000   0.000000   3.619000 (  3.616361)
```

So, in at least this case, unpacking the pairs is better.

Comment: thanks! I was not sure how to deal with the sub array.  Can you explain what the inject code is doing?

Comment: The rdoc describes it best - For each element in enum (ie the array a) the block is passed an accumulator value (sum) and the element. The result of the block becomes the new value for sum. At the end of the iteration, the final value of sum is the return value for the method. Conceptually, it is doing what @LeoCorrea did in his answer.

Comment: Thanks @LeoCorrea. The code was right, just wrote the answer wrong. Answer fixed.

Comment: @justinKo, thanks! I understand the general logic, less of the syntax.  for example, what is the "0" in inject(0)?  I think I understand the rest.

Comment: 0 is the initial accumulator value - ie the first time the block is called, it is the value of `sum`.

Comment: you can (and you should) unpack the pairs so you don't have to write array[0] and array[1].

Comment: Thanks @tokland. I did not know I could do that until I saw the answer from the Tin Man. I updated the answer.

Comment: +1 @tokland. Considering how easy it is to unpack them, it makes no sense to treat them as an array if it's not necessary. Of course that might come at a cost so it might be more efficient to using indexing.

Comment: @theTinMan, a benchmark (see update) shows that unpacking is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I like the inject answer that @JustinKo gave but here's another solution that might be easier to understand if you are new to Ruby.

```
a=[[1,2],[2,2],[3,2],[4,2],[5,2],[6,2]]
sum = 0
a.each { |x, y| sum += y if x >= 2 and x < 4 }
puts sum
#=> 4
```

Comment: Thanks, wanted to avoid the .each as inject is more efficient.

Comment: Actually, running benchmark of both method shows .each being as efficient if not more efficient than .inject in terms of real time speed in seconds.

Comment: interesting, I was always told inject was faster.  Which benchmark gem are you using?  I keep hearing about it, but when I searched rubygems, I find a bunch, not sure which is best.

Comment: Built in Ruby benchmark. In IRB or Pry, just require 'benchmark'

Comment: It might be faster on higher array lengths, I didn't test that end. Although, I'm not sure how it would make much difference. In the end inject still has to iterate through the array I presume.

Comment: If you worry about speed, ruby is not your way. Anyway, `while` works about 2x faster than block iterators.

Comment: Clarity of code is probably the most important thing, but being aware of what is fastest, and incorporating that knowledge into writing clear code, is my goal.

Comment: @LeoCorrea, don't run benchmarks inside IRB or Pry. They have extra overhead that colors the results. Create a simple script and run it so the results reflect Ruby's true speed.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks, I wasn't aware of the overhead. I did write a script and tested it in both irb, pry, and just running the script. The difference wasn't much but still showed the same results.

Answer (score 0):

It's more clearly in ruby to use chains of more simple methods. So:

```
a=[[1,2],[2,2],[3,2],[4,2],[5,2],[6,2]]
a.select{ |i| (2...4).include? i[0] }.map(&:last).reduce(:+)
# => 4
```

Comment: but it's also more expensive to use 3 iterators rather than one.

Comment: It's the same O(n) solution, as other ones

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually what you'd like to use is a list-comphrehension. Alas, Ruby has no built-in syntax for LCs, but a compact+map does the job just fine:

```
a.map { |x, y| y if x >= 2 && x < 4 }.compact.inject(0, :+)
#=> 4
```

If you are writing a medium/large script you'll probably have (and should have) an extensions 
module. Add the required methods so you can write declarative and concise code:

```
a.map_select { |x, y| y if x >= 2 && x < 4 }.sum
```

Or even:

```
a.sum { |x, y| y if x >= 2 && x < 4 }
```